# Spring cloud stream kafka consumer DefaultErrorHandler not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I need help in error handling scenario in spring cloud stream kafka binder. My Application has java 8 consumer of which binding is specified in application.yaml. The consumer is written as :

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<Transaction>> doProcess() {

    return message -> {
        Transaction transaction = message.getPayload();
       
        if(true) {
            throw new RuntimeException("exception!! !!:)");
        }
       Acknowledgment acknowledgment = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, 
       Acknowledgment.class);
       if (acknowledgment != null) {
           System.out.println("Acknowledgment provided");
           acknowledgment.acknowledge();
       }
  }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
spring.application.name: appname
spring.cloud.stream:
  function.definition: doProcess
  kafka:
    default.consumer:
      startOffset: latest
      useNativeDecoding: true
    bindings:
      input.consumer.autoCommitOffset: false

bindings:
  doProcess-in-0:
    destination: kafka.input.topic.name
    group: appGroup
    content-type: application/*+avro
    consumer:
      autoCommitOffset: false.
```

Bean defined are:

```
@Bean
    public ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer> listener() {
        System.out.println(String.format("DEBUG: Bean has bean created."));
        return new KafkaListenerContainerCustomizer();
    }

public class KafkaListenerContainerCustomizer implements ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer> {
    private Object notifier;
    public KafkaListenerContainerCustomizer(Object notifier){
        this.notifier = notifier;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AbstractMessageListenerContainer container, String destinationName, String group) {
        KafkaGlobalErrorHandler eh = new KafkaGlobalErrorHandler(new ExponentialBackOff());
        container.setCommonErrorHandler(eh);
    }
}



public class KafkaGlobalErrorHandler extends DefaultErrorHandler {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaGlobalErrorHandler.class);

    public KafkaGlobalErrorHandler(BackOff backOff) {
        super(backOff);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleRecord(Exception exception, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                             MessageListenerContainer container) {

        LOGGER.error("Error occured while processing: " + ListenerUtils.recordToString(record), exception);
        String topic = record.topic();
        long offset = record.offset();
        int partition = record.partition();
        if (exception.getClass().equals(DeserializationException.class)) {
            DeserializationException deserializationException = (DeserializationException) exception;
            LOGGER.error("Malformed Message Deserialization Exception on topic {}, offset {}, data, {}, msg {}",
                    topic,
                    offset,
                    deserializationException.getData(),
                    deserializationException.getLocalizedMessage());
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("An Exception has occurred. topic {}, offset {}, data, {}, msg {}", topic, offset, partition,
                    exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        consumer.commitSync();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleBatch(Exception exception, ConsumerRecords<?, ?> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                            MessageListenerContainer container, Runnable invokeListener) {

        for (ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record : records) {

            String topic = record.topic();
            long offset = record.offset();
            int partition = record.partition();
            if (exception.getClass().equals(DeserializationException.class)) {
                DeserializationException deserializationException = (DeserializationException) exception;
                LOGGER.error("Malformed Message Deserialization Exception on topic {}, offset {}, data, {}, msg {}",
                        topic,
                        offset,
                        deserializationException.getData(),
                        deserializationException.getLocalizedMessage());
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("An Exception has occurred. topic {}, offset {}, data, {}, msg {}", topic, offset, partition,
                        exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            consumer.commitSync();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleOtherException(Exception thrownException, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                                     MessageListenerContainer container, boolean batchListener) {

        LOGGER.error("Error occurred while not processing records", thrownException);
    }

}
```

Now, I am struggling with error handling :

We need to write the custom exception handler, where we can catch the exception(error in both application code and framework) and send notification to a user group via email in AWS env. But, we are not able to find any error handler which can catch both types of exception. We tried with SeekToCuurentErrorHandler but it did not work. Then I tried with DefaultErrorHandler as suggested in this post : [Spring cloud stream kafka consumer error handling and retries issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70389035/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-consumer-error-handling-and-retries-issues), but it's working only for some exception (i.e able to catch in handleOtherException method), and if consumer code throws any RuntimeException(as given in consumer code attached here), it is not caught by DefaultErrorHandler.

Comment: I don't see how that code will even compile `container.setErrorHandler(eh)` - the `DefaultErrorHandler` is `CommonErrorHandler` and must be set using `setCommonErrorHandler`. If you can't figure it out, post an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace.

Comment: @Gary :Sorry for the mistake in code. Actually I was trying with SeekToCurrentErrorHandler and DefaultErrorHandler in two modules in my project. So, by mistake pasted KafkaListenerContainerCustomizer  of SeekToCurrentErrorHandler. Now, I have corrected that but question is still the same . Please help me in that.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do; `handleRecord` is not called for the DEH, because `remainingRecords` returns true; `handleRemaining` is called and it performs seeks on those records so they will be returned again on the next poll. `>we are not able to find any error handler which can catch both types of exception.` - that doesn't make any sense; all exceptions go to the same EH.

Comment: You should not extend the default EH if you want to handle the exception some other way.

Comment: @Gary: Thanks for your comment but with the same code that I have pasted , if I explicitly  throw RuntimeException  from Kafka Consumer, it is not caught by either handleRemaining or by handleOtherException. What I am trying to do is I just want a common error handler that can catch any exception either from kafka consumer (java8 style consumer) or from kafka container.

Comment: And also I could not find any documentation on how to do error handling if your kafka consumer is java8 java.util.function.Consumer type and mapped with topic on application.yaml

Comment: It is not clear what you are saying; please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can understand what the problem is. `handleOtherException` is normally called only when the `KafkaConsumer` throws an exception, `handleRemaining` is called whenever your code (Consumer) throws an exception.